# Grails 4 - Google Cloud Platform deployment keeps restarting

Tags: spring, grails, google-cloud-platform

My Grails 4 application, deployed to GCP appears to be trying to start up after being deployed but never comes up properly. Application requests return a 500 response. There are no errors or clues with DEBUG log level output at the root level.

The same application runs fine locally in development mode.

The production configuration is as per the Grails 3 deployment (to GCP) guide except for the adjustments that were necessary to make it work for Grails 4/Java 11.
Most of the bootstrapping appears to carry out as expected;

- Spring Security configures successfully
- Spring Security REST configures successfully
- Spring beans are registered
- Connects to Cloud SQL instance
- Database schema is created (by Liquibase)
- Plugins are loaded successfully

Then it gets to the following familiar lines of output logging;

```
INFO --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO --- [main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
INFO --- [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
```

and restarts..

while normally, the next phase of bootstrapping (happens locally) would be;

```
[restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 42018 ms
```

Probably a long shot question but any level of clues or suggestions would be much appreciated.

I've run out of doors to open. :-(

Comment: I've just tried a very basic "helloworld" application and got the same result. Seems like full support for Grails 4 on GCP may not yet be achieved and so I'm going to park this for now. I'm going to leave the story open though for any additional contributions

Answer (score 0):

You could try to update Tomcat version just in case.

> But looking at Grails documentation:
>
> https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html
>
> There's some configuration made when you upgrade to Grails 4 from
>   Grails 3.3.x to prevents the server from restarting when views or
>   message bundles are changed.

Either modifying a gsp in Grails 4 M2 cause the application to restart.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11284

Comment: Thanks Toni. I'm using whatever the latest embedded Tomcat is included in Grails 4.0 and so maybe the next release will have a newer version or I might just try and force it.
On the modifying gsp (or anything for that matter), correct me if I'm wrong but once bundled into a single jar file artifact, I'm not sure this is possible.